# Flask SQLAlchemy Many to Many Delete Element

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My Flask site has Suggestions and Users.

```
class Suggestion(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_nickname = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.nickname'))
    voters = db.relationship('User', secondary=votes, lazy='dynamic')

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    suggestions = db.relationship('Suggestion', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    votes = db.relationship('Suggestion', secondary=votes, lazy='dynamic')
```

I have set up a many to many relationship between the two as such.

```
votes = db.Table('votes',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('suggestion_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('suggestion.id'))
)
```

When I try to delete a Suggestion inside my views.py I get an error.

The View:

```
@app.route('/_delete_suggestion', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def delete_suggestion():
    user_nickname = request.form.get('user_nickname')
    user = User.query.filter_by(nickname=user_nickname).first()
    sugg_id = request.form.get('sugg_id')
    sugg = Suggestion.query.filter_by(id=sugg_id).first()
    if user.is_special:
        db.session.delete(sugg)
        db.session.commit()
    else:
        flash('You are not cool enough to do that!')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return

@app.route('/_upvote', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def upvote():
    user_nickname = request.form.get('user_nickname')
    user = User.query.filter_by(nickname=user_nickname).first()
    sugg_id = request.form.get('sugg_id')
    sugg = Suggestion.query.filter_by(id=sugg_id).first()
    if sugg.voters.filter_by(nickname=user_nickname).first() is not None:
        print("ERR", file=sys.stderr)
    else:
        print("VOTED", file=sys.stderr)
        sugg.score += 1
        sugg.voters.append(user)
        user.votes.append(sugg)
        db.session.add(sugg)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    return
```

The Error:

```
StaleDataError: DELETE statement on table 'votes' expected to delete 2 row(s); Only 4 were matched.
```

What I Know:

- I can delete Suggestions that don't have any votes.

What I Have Tried:

- I tried adding `view-only=True` into the models.
- I tried removing all a suggestion's voters and removing the suggestion from all users votes before deleting.
- I have been looking at all the posts form StackOverflow and Google related to this issue without any luck.

What am I missing? This is driving me up a wall!

EDIT:
Inside a python interpreter, I tried to the following.

```
s = Suggestion.query.first()
for v in s.voters.all():
    s.voters.remove(v)
s.voters.all()
```

This then crashed and produced the same StaleDataError.

Comment: Is there any reason you define the backrefs for on both sides of the relationship? You typically only need to specify it on one end or the other. Because, right now you have `User.upvotes` and `User.votes` which are essentially doing the same thing and you have `Suggestion.fans` and `Suggestions.voters`. Maybe this is part of the problem?

Comment: I removed the Suggestion's backref but am still running into the same error.

Comment: As a side note that error message is hilarious. "I expected 2 but only got 4"

Comment: You should remove both backrefs. If you have a backref on `voters`, for example, you don't need to specify the `votes` relationship and vice versa. To specify both sides of the relationship independently, use [`back_populates`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates). I suspect this is the problem because you essentially have two rows in `votes` for every vote you actually have (and then 2 becomes 4).

Comment: I have tried setting both Models using back_populates and got the same error. I'll try removing both backrefs and recreating the DB to see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: have you been able to reproduce this from a brand new database? You may have some lingering entries within the association table causing issues.

Comment: @Suever, Yes, I just reproduced it with a brand new db. Removing both backrefs still has the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I was adding into the Many to Many array twice inside the `_upvote` route.

Original `_upvote` snippet:

```
print("VOTED", file=sys.stderr)
sugg.score += 1
sugg.voters.append(user)
user.votes.append(sugg)
db.session.add(sugg)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

Fixed `_upvote` snippet:

```
print("VOTED", file=sys.stderr)
sugg.score += 1
sugg.voters.append(user)
db.session.add(sugg)
db.session.commit()
```